# How to handle jOOQ depreciation warning on procedure that returns a trigger?

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I use the following stored procedure to maintain the edit time on a few tables via triggers on those tables:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maintain_edit_time()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $t_edit_time$
        BEGIN
        NEW.edit_timestamp = NOW();
        RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $t_edit_time$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When generating jOOQ objects for the database in question, I get the following generated code:

```
 /**
 * @deprecated Unknown data type. Please define an explicit {@link org.jooq.Binding} to specify how this type should be handled. Deprecation can be turned off using <deprecationOnUnknownTypes/> in your code generator configuration.
 */
@java.lang.Deprecated
public static Object maintainEditTime(Configuration configuration) {
    MaintainEditTime f = new MaintainEditTime();

    f.execute(configuration);
    return f.getReturnValue();
}

/**
 * @deprecated Unknown data type. Please define an explicit {@link org.jooq.Binding} to specify how this type should be handled. Deprecation can be turned off using <deprecationOnUnknownTypes/> in your code generator configuration.
 */
@java.lang.Deprecated
public static Field<Object> maintainEditTime() {
    MaintainEditTime f = new MaintainEditTime();

    return f.asField();
}
```

I assume this is because I do not have a jOOQ binding between TRIGGER and a Java object.  However, I do not have a clue what I would define this binding as, nor do I have any need for a binding to exist.

**Left alone, though, this generates a compile warning.  What's the cleanest, easiest way to resolve this?**

Options seem to include turning off deprecation, using ignoreProcedureReturnValues, or creating a binding.  Ideally, I'd like to simply not generate a Java object for this procedure, but I could not find a way to do that.

Using ignoreProcedureReturnValues globally effects the project just because of this, which is fine for now, I don't have other procedures at all, much less others with a return value.  But, I hate to limit future use.  Also, I'm unclear one what the comment "This feature is deprecated as of jOOQ 3.6.0 and will be removed again in jOOQ 4.0." means on the jOOQ site under this flag.  Is the flag going away, or is support for stored procedure return types going away?  A brief dig through the jOOQ github issues didn't yield me an answer.

Tempted to simply turn off deprecation.  This also seems like a global and not beneficial change, but it would serve the purpose.

If I created a binding, I have no idea what it would do, or how to define it since TRIGGER really isn't a sensible thing to bind a Java object to.  I assume I'd specify  as TRIGGER in the forcedType element, but then the Java binding seems like a waste of time at best and misleading at worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already found the perfect solution, [which you documented in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086314/521799). I'll answer your various other questions here, for completeness' sake

> Using ignoreProcedureReturnValues globally effects the project just because of this, which is fine for now, I don't have other procedures at all, much less others with a return value. But, I hate to limit future use. Also, I'm unclear one what the comment "This feature is deprecated as of jOOQ 3.6.0 and will be removed again in jOOQ 4.0." means on the jOOQ site under this flag. Is the flag going away, or is support for stored procedure return types going away? A brief dig through the jOOQ github issues didn't yield me an answer.

That flag has been introduced because of a backwards incompatible change in the code generator that affected only SQL Server: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4106

In SQL Server, procedures always return an `INT` value, just like functions. This change allowed for fetching this `INT` value using jOOQ generated code. In some cases, it was desireable to not have this feature enabled when upgrading from jOOQ 3.5 to 3.6. Going forward, we'll always generate this `INT` return type on SQL Server stored procedures.

This is why the flag has been deprecated from the beginning, as we don't encourage its use, except for backwards compatibility usage. It probably won't help you here.

Stored procedure support is definitely not going to be deprecated.

> Tempted to simply turn off deprecation. This also seems like a global and not beneficial change, but it would serve the purpose.

Why not. A quick workaround. You don't have to use all the generated code. The deprecation is there to indicate that calling this generated procedure probably won't work out of the box, so its use is discouraged.

> If I created a binding, I have no idea what it would do, or how to define it since TRIGGER really isn't a sensible thing to bind a Java object to. I assume I'd specify as TRIGGER in the forcedType element, but then the Java binding seems like a waste of time at best and misleading at worst.

Indeed, that wouldn't really add much value to your use cases as you will never directly call the trigger function in PostgreSQL.

Again, your own solution using `<exclude>` is the ideal solution here. In the future, we might offer a new code generation configuration flag that allows for turning on/off the generation of trigger functions, with the default being off: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9270

Comment: Thanks as always, Lukas.  This is a fantastic level of detail and left me much more confident I made the correct decision.  If I had a large number of trigger functions, I would be very interested in the implementation of 9270.  Given that I only have one and don't think many more will be added, the single exclude will work for me for a long time.

Comment: @Evan: Well, if you had a large number of trigger functions, you could place a SQL statement in your `<exclude>` element that produces the regular expression based on a query against `information_schema.routines`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Evan: Oh no. We haven't implemented that yet: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6489. Too bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, after noting that an ideal way to do this would be to ignore that procedure, I did find how to ignore the procedure by name in the generally excellent jOOQ website documentation.  Don't know how I missed in on first pass.  If I needed to call this procedure in Java, I'm unclear which of the above options I would have used.

Luckily, there was no need for this procedure to be referenced in code, and I excluded it as shown below in in the jOOQ XML configuration.

```
<excludes>
    databasechangelog.*
    | maintain_edit_time
</excludes>
```